# Moving first item in array to the last position

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to move the position of the first item of an array at the press of a button,
I tried using `array.push(array.shift());` but it doesn't work

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-zo3rn?file=/DailyScheduler.js)

```js
import React from "react";

const DailySchedule = () => {
  let exerciseList = ["exercise 1", "exercise 2", "exercise 3"];

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <h2>Warm-up</h2>

        <ul>
          {exerciseList.map((exrcs, idx) => {
            return (
              <li>
                {exrcs}{" "}
                {idx === 0 && (
                  <button
                    onClick={() =>
                      console.log(exerciseList.push(exerciseList.shift()))
                    }
                  >
                    Done
                  </button>
                )}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It does work, but push does not return the array itself. So you are logging the wrong thing.

Comment: I got it, now it works but it won't rerender the map() list

Comment: I'm not too familiar with react but I suspect it relies on the list being immutable. You could just create a new reference by spreading it into itself: `exerciseList = [...exerciseList];` before moving the element. Not 100% sure, so maybe someone more familiar with react can confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to log the return value of push method. In your case it would be 3 because list size is 3 after pushing one element.
Instead of it you need to log the list.

```
exerciseList.push(exerciseList.shift()); //this will move the top element to the bottom
console.log(exerciseList); //this will give you the updated list
```

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the wrong thing. Push will return the new length of the array.

However, you should also reassign the reference of the `exerciseList`, otherwise the change is not detected. (I think). So perhaps this will work better:

```
exerciseList = [
  exerciseList.shift(),
  ...excerciseList
];
```